# Protocol method requirement - allow method parameter to be replaced/overriden by conforming type?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I have a protocol, `Device`, which contains the required method `makeACopy(device: Device) -> Device`. When a struct conforms to `Device`, it should specify itself in place of `Device`.

Now, I want to make my `Phone` struct conform to `Device`. However, when I conform to the `makeACopy(device: Device) -> Device` requirement with `makeACopy(device: Phone) -> Phone`, I get this error:

> Type 'Phone' does not conform to protocol 'Device'

Here's my code:

```
protocol Device {
    var name: String { get set }
    func makeACopy(device: Device) -> Device
}

struct Phone: Device { /// Error: Type 'Phone' does not conform to protocol 'Device'
    var name = "My Phone"
    func makeACopy(device: Phone) -> Phone { /// my attempt to conform to `Device`'s method requirement
        return Phone(name: self.name)
    }
}
```

Since `Phone` conforms to `Device`, I thought my `makeACopy(device: Phone) -> Phone` method would satisfy the protocol. But apparently not.

How can I make `Device`'s `func makeACopy(device: Device) -> Device` requirement accept protocol-conforming *substitutes* for the parameter? For example, replacing `device: Device` with `device: Phone`?

Comment: So can `makeACopy` return a *different* type, or only the *same* type?

Comment: @jnpdx `makeACopy` should return the type of whatever struct conformed to it. Maybe I should be using generics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for this, which guarantees that both the input and output are the same type *and* conform to `Device`:

```
protocol Device {
    var name: String { get set }
    func makeACopy(device: Self) -> Self //<-- Note that `Self` is used instead of `Device`
}
```

Comment: Oh wow — so *that*'s what capitalized `Self` is for. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah -- capitalized `Self` is the type, not the actual instance.